# How to set different color theme for Terminal and GUI?

Tags: vimrc, colorscheme

Since there are themes only work on GUI, so is it possible to make the Terminal to use another theme than GUI one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put the terminal colorscheme in your vimrc (usually `~/.vimrc` or `$HOME\_vimrc` on Windows) and the gui colorscheme in your gvimrc. Create `~/.gvimrc` / `$HOME\_gvimrc` if you don't already have that file.

This works because gvimrc is only read when you run gvim and it is read in after vimrc

Comment: Sorry I didn't state my question correctly, I'm using macvim, and it seems like macvim is still take .vimrc and ignore .gvimrc? I'm debugging for this.

Comment: @job_start no, macvim reads the gvimrc. see `:help gvimrc` and scroll a bit for the right locations

Comment: I accidentally typed `colorscheme =tone` in `.gvimrc`! Problem solved it's my typo, lol!